# Open a file in a new browser window after having written it (with fopen)

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple order system where several numbers (filled in inside a form) are written to another .php file (may be .html also), using the `fopen` function. This works fine, but after writing to the file, I want the browser to actually open that written file, preferably in a *new* browser window. This way my client can use this to print, use as an invoice, etc.

Now I'm still a rookie on php grounds and am not experienced with the use of `fopen`. But everywhere I look for tutorials etc., it's said that `fopen` opens (or writes of course) a file, but it doesn't for as far as I've experienced. It just seems to allow access to the specified file to write and read, rather to actually display the newly written page.

To avoid any confusion: I do NOT want to open links like other questions here on SO state.

My code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="amountTuna" name="numberTuna" value="0"/>
  <input type="text" id="amountCheese" name="numberCheese" value="0"/>
  <input name="send" id="send" type="submit" value="Post order" />
</form>

<?php
if (array_key_exists('send', $_POST)) { 
  $order = "order.php";
  $fh = fopen($order, 'w') or die("can't open file");//file handler

  fwrite($fh, "Tuna sandwiches: " . stripslashes($_POST['numberTuna']));
  fwrite($fh, "Cheese sandwiches: " . stripslashes($_POST['numberCheese']));

  $fh = fopen($factuur, 'r');
  $fileip = fread($fh, filesize($factuur));
  fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

Trying different `fopen` parameters such as `'w'`,`'r'`,`'r+'` etc doesn't seem to make any difference. Removing `fclose($fh)` doesn't seem to make any difference either.

Comment: This does seem a strange way of recording an order - have you considered using a DB to store orders in ? this would make things a whole lot easier recording / displaying and searching to name a few advantages

Comment: Why do you want write to a PHP file ???

Comment: @ManseUK Well yes, I might consider doing that later. But to be specific, it's not a webshop kind of order system, instead the shop owner just fills in numbers for the ordered sandwiches and wants it on a page for giving it to the delivery guy, and/or perhaps using it as an invoice for his customer. The 'client' is actually a friend of mine so we're doing this step by step :). Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: @Baba It may be an html file too, the important thing is that it needs be be a printable page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use JS script to open new window. For example right after `fclose($fh)`:

```
echo "<script>window.open($order, '_blank'); window.focus();</script>";
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to work that way. Neither if i do it like `echo "<script>window.open(".$order.", '_blank'); window.focus();</script>";`

Comment: but window opens? if so - just check the path and insert correct one.

Comment: No window opens - and the order.php file (`$order`) is in the same folder. p.s. changing `<script>` to `<script type=\"text/javascript\">` doesn't seem to solve the problem either.

Comment: try to escape: `echo "<script>window.open('$order', '_blank'); window.focus();</script>";
`

Comment: Filename should be enclosed like '$fileName'. For me it is working  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.open('$fileName', '_blank'); window.focus();</script>";

Answer (score 2):

Storing things in a database would likely be a lot easier.

That said, using fopen is to open the file itself, opening the written file in a new browser window will require some client-side scripting (i.e. Javascript) to load the newly created file.

Google Javascript window.open().

Tom

Comment: Thanks, but in php this isn't possible? I find it kinda confusing that 'fopen' doesn't really open the file but instead *access to the file* instead. If I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained it a bit better. When a browser connects to your server anything with a .php extension is processed as a PHP file, all the results are sent as a plain HTML page to the web browser.

Because of this you can't use PHP to interact with the client computer. Using the fopen() method opens the file from the file system for the PHP application on the server to be able to read / write / modify with the respected flags.

Hope that's a bit clearer!

Comment: I mean that every tutorial, documentation etc. calls it 'opening a file' while I expect it to actually be opened in the browser, I wasn't referring to your explanation ;) And I understand it now, I'll keep it in mind :D

Comment: I understood, I just realised that my explanation was a  bit "iffy" 

Good luck with the order system =D

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to write to a printable page .. have you tried [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Example

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $file = "test.html";
    $data = "Tuna sandwiches: " . stripslashes($_POST['numberTuna']) . "<br>";
    $data .= "Cheese sandwiches: " . stripslashes($_POST['numberCheese']) . "<br>";
    touch($file);
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
}
```

Comment: isn't this pretty much the same as what i did with fopen?

Comment: Big Difference  `file_put_contents` = `fopen + fwrite + fclose`

Comment: Oh so actually a shortcut? I'll remember that for bigger pieces of code :)